# read lines after specific string by c#

Tags: c#, string

how to read lines after specific string and end reading when reach specific string

this is my text file

```
bla bla bla
bla bla bla 
bla bla vasdasdasd
<rs:data>
please read me se
please read me gr
please read me ew
please read me se
please read me cg
</rs:data>
saddsagkobn
bla bla bla
```

if i use this code

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\mytext.txt");
```

it will read all the lines

how to read lines between `<rs:data>` and `</rs:data>` ????

Comment: You are not trying to read XML as plain text, are you?

Comment: I see. For future questions that can't use well known approaches (like in your case it looked like you trying to parse XML with `String.IndexOf`) consider adding something like "if it would be XML I could use `XDocument`, but it is just XML fragment inside plain text" to show that you did research on the possible solutions and avoid potential comments or even down-votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var result = lines.SkipWhile(x => x != "<rs:data>")  // skips everything before 
                  .Skip(1)                           // and <rs:data> itself
                  .TakeWhile(x => x != "</rs:data>") // and take up to </rs:data>
                  .ToList();                         // as List<string>
```

Comment: +1 this is how "alot" looks like for those who don't know - http://loveandasandwich.deviantart.com/art/I-LIKE-THIS-ALOT-181482531

Comment: Great! Superb and very useful.